# Hotstar.com not working on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, browser, streaming

**Hotstar**.com is more like Indian Netflix. It's a video streaming service and have apps as well as web versions. hotstar.com open on Firefox, Chromium and Google Chrome in Ubuntu. We are able to browse content and select, click " Play " as well.

After that, the content never plays. It keeps loading and loading with a spinning circular icon in the middle of the player.

Any possible fix for this issue ? Thanks.

PS: Works fine on Windows.

Comment: sudohotstar trick does not work anymore. :(

Comment: if you want an update to that post, set a bounty on it. That's one of the standard bounty reasons.